# Object access and modification through derived class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a `BaseListWindow` class as a Base class for my others `ListWindow`. Every `ListWindow` manipulates one list of differents objects (list of cars or trains or planes). Each list of objects is a member of an other object called Vehicles.

```
 public class Vehicles
    {
        private List<Car> _cars;
        private List<Train> _trains;
        // ... getters and setters too
   }
```

`BaseListWindow` Constructor takes a Vehicle object and then a derived class like `CarsListWindow` uses a member to define which list to use in the `BaseListWindow` class. Operations on `_vehicles.List<Car>` are made both in `BaseListWindow` and `CarsListWindow`. 
Here are the definitions of BaseListWindow and CarListWindow

```
public abstract class BaseListWindow<T> : Window where T : IListElem 
{
    protected Vehicles _vehicles;
    public List<T> _element;

  public BaseListWindow(Vehicles v, List<T> listElement)
    {
        _vehicles = v;
        _element = listElement;
    }
}

public partial class CarsListWindow : BaseListWindow<Car>
      {
      public CarsListWindow(Vehicle v, List<Car> listElement) : base(v, listElement)
        {
            _vehicles = v;
            _vehicles.Cars = listElement;
        }
 }
```

I have several questions :

1. Where to initialize the members of my derived class ? In the base constructor or in the derived class ?
2. How to manipulate the list of object in the base class ? When i try to modify _element in the base class the object is always null, and i suspect the Vehicles object in the base class is not the same as the one in the derived class.
3. Is it a good approach to use an object Vehicles holding few differences lists of objects and then use a `BaseListWindow` and a derived class to access and modify those objects.

My idea is that `BaseListWindow` holds the object Vehicles so it can access any of the list of objects, but my problem is to access this list of object in the base class. This is hard since the type of the list is different for each derived class.

I hope I'm not missing the point of all this.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your questions. Members of the derived class only exist in your derived class (or a derived class of this derived class) so you can't initialize them in the base constructor. The _element is the same in the derived and in the base object because those are the same object. But intrinsically I think that your main problem is that you're mixing View and Model layers. You Window class should only display data, not store them. The data should be stored in your Model layer and you should have a ViewModel layer between those two. Your design makes you create a derived class

Comment: of Window and make it abstract: an abstract  Control is weird, override a Control to make it abstract is weirder.

Comment: Ok, i tought i was on the wrong approach, i will try to understand MVVM better and apply it. Thank you both !

Comment: Don't do this. See MVVM and use [datatemplating](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html) to create sets of ViewModels and Views. ViewModels then can be inherited from some base class where you put all base functionality.

Comment: Can i leave this question as is ? I can't accept any answer as there aren't any. The comment solved my problem but i can't upvote them.